# Issue with android sql-query..."no such column"?

Tags: java, android, sql

I want to use a SQL database to store records for a game. Actually I don't have a clue about SQL. I have a class "Records" which should manage the in and Output of records. Additionally I have a class SQLDatabaseHelper which provides the SQL-Database.

My Problem is the following line:

```
crsRecord = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(QUERY_GET_RECORD + category, null);
```

I got always the error "No such column: SYS103"
"SYS103" is a name of a category. I don't know why it can be read. Do you have any idea?

SQL table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE records (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            category VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            displaytime VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
            recordtime VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
```

I guess writing works just reading doesn't work.

```
public class Records {
            private SQLiteOpenHelper sqliteOpenHelper;
            private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase;

            private static final String INSERT_NEW_RECORD = "insert into records(category, displayrecord, timerecord) values(";
            private static final String QUERY_GET_RECORD = "SELECT * FROM  records WHERE category = ";

            public Records(Context context){
                sqliteOpenHelper = new SQLDatabaseHelper(context);
                sqliteDatabase = sqliteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }

            public void addRecord(String category, String displaytime, String timerecord){
                ContentValues data = new ContentValues();

                data.put("category", category);
                data.put("displaytime", displaytime);
                data.put("recordtime", timerecord);

                sqliteDatabase.insert("records", null, data);
        //      sqliteDatabase.execSQL(INSERT_NEW_RECORD + category + ", " + strTime + ", " + dblTime + ");");
            }

            public String[] getRecord(String category){
                String[] record = new String[3];
                Cursor crsRecord;
                try{
                    crsRecord = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(QUERY_GET_RECORD + category, null);
                }catch(SQLiteException e){
                    Log.d("database", e.getMessage());
                    String[] nullRecord = {category, "00:00.0", "0"};
                    return nullRecord;
                }

                int i=0;


                while(crsRecord.moveToNext()){
                    record[i] = crsRecord.getString(0);
                    i++;
                }

                return record;

            }
        }

    public class SQLDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private Context context;

        public SQLDatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(
                context,
                context.getResources().getString(R.string.dbname),
                null,
                Integer.parseInt(context.getResources().getString(R.string.version)));
             this.context=context;
         }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            for(String sql : context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.create)){
                db.execSQL(sql);
            }
            Log.d("Database", "creat succesfully");
         }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
```

My method to get data out of the database, but for some reason the columnIndex is alway -1:

```
public String[] getRecord(String category){
    String[] record = new String[3];
    Cursor crsRecord;

        crsRecord = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(QUERY_GET_RECORD, new String[]{ category } );

    int i=0;
    crsRecord.moveToFirst();
    while(!crsRecord.isAfterLast()){

        // Instead of using an int literal to get the colum index,
        // use the getColumnIndex method
        int index = crsRecord.getColumnIndex(category);
        if (index == -1) {
            String[] nullRecord = {category, "00:00.0", "0"};
            return nullRecord;
        }
        else {
            record[i] = crsRecord.getString(index);
            i++;
        }

        crsRecord.moveToNext();
    }



    while(crsRecord.moveToNext()){
        record[i] = crsRecord.getString(0);
        i++;
    }

    return record;

}
```

Comment: Do you notice anything wrong with: `private static final String INSERT_NEW_RECORD = "insert into records(category, displayrecord, timerecord) values(";` ? The column names specified there in comparison to the column names for the table creation?

Comment: INSERT_NEW_RECORD was used before. Now it is a comment. But I tried to use it again and I changed the INSERT_NEW_RECORD line but the only difference is, that I got an other error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":12": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: insert into records(category, displayrecord, recordtime) values(SYS103, 00:12.8, 5819);

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape your parameters.

As is, your code executes the query:

```
SELECT * FROM  records WHERE category = SYS103
```

That's not valid SQL. It should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  records WHERE category = 'SYS103'
```

and you need to escape apostrophes. You'd be better off relying on `rawQuery` to escape your parameters:

```
private static final String QUERY_GET_RECORD 
                            = "SELECT * FROM  records WHERE category = ?";
```

and

```
crsRecord = 
    sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(QUERY_GET_RECORD, new String[]{ category } );
```

Comment: Thank you for that...now I have another error in the "insert" line. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do the same thing there, if you want to use rawQuery: `rawQuery( "INSERT INTO records( category, displayTime, recordTime )VALUES(?,?,?)", new String[]{ cat, dt, rt } );` You might be better off using `insert`.

Comment: Now it works without error, but I am not able to get data out of my database. I have updated my entry above.

Comment: You're not actually accessing the the cursor in getRecord. Add something like `if( crsRecord.moveToFirst() ) { return new String{} { crsRecord.getString(0), crsRecord.getString(1), crsRecord.getString(2) }; } else { ... return null record ... }`

Comment: Oh yea...according to the Debugger I access the cursor. See the new code I attached. But the Problem is I got always "getColumnIndex" = -1...what means column doesn't exist, but it should because I added it before.

Comment: You're doing `getColumnIndex( category )` -- `category` is "SYS103". What you'd want to do is `getColumnIndex( "category" )`.